# How to change value in object of object from NSMutableDictionary? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I read data from plist to NSMutableDictionary. However, data is quite complex.

Data contains an array, and in each object of an array is a dictionary, etc...

How can I change value of an object in a deep level of that NSMutableDictionary?

```
plist
|- NSArray
     |- item: NSDictionary
                |- ...
                    |- object
```

```
NSDictionary* data = [self readFromPlist];
NSMutableDictionary* mutableData = [data mutableCopy];
....
```

Note: code is written by Objective-C

Comment: Iterate, use custom objects, to represent your model, and make "quick" access?

Comment: but how can I change the value? because it's immutable.

Comment: Your root dictionary may be mutable, but your child objects are `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, etc, which are not mutable.

Comment: Indeed, is there any way to convert entire NSDictionary into NSMutableDictionary ?

Comment: You mean making all the nested objects mutable as well? You could do that by iterating over the original dictionary, and then make each one mutable. But I highly recommend the suggestion by @Larme by using custom objects for your data structure. So for instance, if the root dictionary is really a person, create an array of persons objects, etc.